# Infragistics.WebUI.WebDataInput.WebTextEdit

Tags: infragistics

I am working to upgrade our application that uses Infragistics 2005 v5.3 to use Infragistics 2009 v9.1. I used the version upgrade utility to have the solution upgraded. However, I am stuck with an error saying:

> The type 'Infragistics.WebUI.WebDataInput.WebTextEdit' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Infragistics.WebUI.WebDataInput.v5.3, Version=5.3.20053.1106, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'.

I am baffled why the code would look for reference for Infragistics 2005. The 2005 version is not referenced anywhere in the solution. I have updated the web.config to use 2009 version. All the references have been cleaned. I read in another blog that it could be a license issue and wiping the data within License.licx file might help. Tried that but did not work. Is WebTextEdit not available in 2009 version? What am I missing??

Comment: Did the below answer help, @ishanmeh?

Answer (score 1):

WebTextEdit is available in 2009 version. It seems that you may have missed cleaning some references. I would double check again for old references. Also try to remove any WebTextEdit and WebDataInput controls from your app and drag-n-drop the same from your Visual Studio toolbox.